PowerShell How does this work: $rv = 1 | Select-Object -Property Name, Type, Value
I was searching on here for information to quickly find all registry key properties with PowerShell v5.1 and found a script that works perfectly but I don't understand how one of the lines works and can't find any info about it. Also, this is my first time posting on here, so please let me know if I need to correct anything.
This is the line I'm looking to get more info about how and why it works:
$rv = 1 | Select-Object -Property Name, Type, Value
I've read the manual for Select-Object but don't see any info that says it can create new properties. Is there a link someone can please share that points me to info that explains how a string can be piped to Select-Object to create new properties?
Here's the script:
function Get-RegistryValue
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        $RegistryKey
    )

    $key = Get-Item -Path "Registry::$RegistryKey"
    $key.GetValueNames() |
    ForEach-Object {
        $name = $_
        $rv = 1 | Select-Object -Property Name, Type, Value
        $rv.Name = $name
        $rv.Type = $key.GetValueKind($name)
        $rv.Value = $key.GetValue($name)
        $rv
  
    }
}

Here are the links to the pages I found the info:

Powershell how to find the property type of a registry item property
Getting Registry Values and Value Types
Reading Registry Values with Type


"... When you select properties, Select-Object returns new objects that have only the specified properties." it's right there in the description :)

@MathiasR.Jessen Does it matter what I pipe into Select-Object? most examples I've seen use 1 | Select-Object. Does the 1 mean anything or can I pipe any string into Select-Object?

It matters in terms of the initial property values on the resulting object - an empty string (eg. "" |Select ... is fairly common too). But it doesn't matter in the sense that you shouldn't be doing it either way - using Select-Object to "blueprint" new custom objects like this is a bit of an antipattern, either use Select-Object to select the actual property values up front, or use [pscustomobject]@{ ... } instead

@MathiasR.Jessen Thank you! I appreciate your help. You answered all my questions.

Simple: Select-Object returns a [PSCustomObject] with only the declared Properties out of any object passed to it.
It's in the Docs
